# C# Unity Raycast through an object without having to ignore it and still hit it

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Esstinaly what I am trying to do is have a Raycast pass though an object and hit another object inside without ignoring the first object, so if the player has there mouse over the first object but not the second it will only hit the first object but if the mouse is over both it will hit only the second object, I can provide visual reference if possible it is only to display some text about said second object.

```
        Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        RaycastHit hitInfo;


        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hitInfo))
        {

            {
                NameTag = hitInfo.transform.name;   //Send information of the Object to the GUI Label

                hoverOverActive = true;
```

This is the basic Raycast script I have .

Comment: raycast return only the first object that touch. You need to use raycastall if need to detect more than 1 collider. If you attach any image i can understand better what you need, and i think is possible with raycast and layermask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is a **Raycast Mask**. This allows you to specify a layer of which when a Raycast hits it, it will be ignored.

In the Unity Editor you will need to create a **new layer** and remember its value,
e.g `ignoreLayer`

In your raycast code you will need to set this layer as your 'mask' in order for it to become ignored:
e.g

`public int ignoreLayer = 8`

In, `Physics.Raycast(ray, out hitInfo)` you specify your mask here as you can pass it in optionally to `Physics.Raycast`
Link to Unity Documentation: http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html

`public static bool Raycast(Vector3 origin, Vector3 direction, float maxDistance = Mathf.Infinity, int layerMask = DefaultRaycastLayers, QueryTriggerInteraction queryTriggerInteraction = QueryTriggerInteraction.UseGlobal);`

This video on Youtube explains how to use Raycast Masking very, very well so I'll link this in for you also: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XO6KCCtGPpA

Comment: The question is a bit strangely written, but the OP said `without ignoring the first object`. I think the solution for him is to do 2 raycasts, one that may hit the second object, and if it doesn't make a new raycast for the first object.

Comment: Thank you all this is a big help , i will ask again if i need any further help , but this looks to be everything i need.