# How to fix the rendering of laser with respect to the UI canvas

Tags: unity-game-engine, oculus

Added some UI elements inside a canvas in world-space render mode. There is an issue with the occlusion of UI elements with respect to the laser pointer. The pointer here is made from a line renderer. Here are the things that have been tried and still the pointer does not properly occlude the canvas.

- changing the hierarchy
- changing the z-order
- changing the sorting order

The source code is from Unity and is available [here](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/XR-Interaction-Toolkit-Examples). There is no related script that requires modification. Seems like a setting or shader change might only be required here.

[image: Laser occlusion with UI]

Comment: Don't think it is trivial. Afaik this was always the case with Unity UI so far.. element at the bottom of the Hierarchy is always rendered last -> on top of the other elements

Comment: updated the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to write a custom shader to test for depth, but this would be a very expensive shader - and it looks like you want to use it on VR, and I would not recommend to use it like so.

Over-engineered solution and still not very cheap but cheaper solution would be to render UI onto a camera that renders into `RenderTarget` and passes the input to the UI.

1. Create a camera - with Redner Target output
2. Create canvas that uses Screen Space - Camera
3. Attach the camera to the Canvas
4. Put Plane in world space and use RenderTarget as material
5. Add a script that would allow passing RayCasts through RenderTarget to UI. [Possible soltuion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37252090/c-sharp-unity-raycast-through-an-object-without-having-to-ignore-it-and-still-hi)

Few notes:

- Camera needs to be disabled for as long as it is possible to save performance and only updated via `Camera.Render()` when UI is updated.
- This solution would still be expensive
- Adds a lot of complexity to a simple problem
- Adds the possibility to "wrap" UI around meshes

**EDIT:** After edit its much simpler problem!

UI is rendered at `RenderQueue = 3000` you probably have unlit material as a line-renderer which has `RenderQueue = 2450`.

You need to create a material with `RenderQueue >= 3000` for your line renderer

If you don't want to create new material, you can change it from code

```
// use this with caution! As this can affect other materials when run in editor!
meshRenderer.material.renderQueue = 3100;
```

**EDIT 2:** If you have URP installed you might need to change the default material to something from URP. Default material uses Legacy shader which causes issues with the Line Renderer and UI.

Comment: let me try the solution and comment if it works, if it does would mark it as the answer :) upvoted already